# AngularJs Modules Dependency Injection Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i'm having some issues with AngularJs, whenever i try to load more than one factory file in my index file (Where i initialize angular JS). Everything loads well but my Places factory refuses to initialize and i get this error at my console. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=PlacesProvider

This is my app.js file

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.utils', 'app.configs', 'app.factories', 'app.ctrls']);
})();
```

I have loaded the JavaScript files for these dependencies in my index file like so

```
<!-- Angular -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/vendor/angular/angular.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/vendor/angular/angular-route.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/vendor/bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/vendor/angular/ocLazyLoad.js') }}
    <!-- App -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/app.js') }}
    <!-- Angular Configurations -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/configs/routes.js') }}
    <!-- Angular services -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/services/Users.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/services/Places.js') }} 
    <!-- Angular directives -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/directives/foundation.js') }}   
    <!-- Angular controllers -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/frontend/src/controllers/mainCtrl.js') }}
<!-- End call for javascript files -->
```

This are my factory files:

Users Factory

```
(function(){
    // Initialize angular module
    var app = angular.module("app.factories, []");
    // Initialize user factory
    app.factory('Users', ["$http", function ($http) {
        // Define variables

        return {
            // My functions
        };
    }]);

})();
```

Places Factory

```
(function(){
    // Initialize angular module
    var app = angular.module("app.factories", []);
    // Initialize places factory
    app.factory('Places', ["$http", function ($http) {
        // Define variables
        return {
        // My functions
        };
    }]);

})();
```

Comment: Have you initialised the `app.factories` module (`angular.module("app.factories", [...]);`)?

Comment: @Clive Yes i have. Just added the square brackets in the initialization now this is the error i get, Unknown Provider.

Comment: I doubt that's the full error message. Always post the full error message

Comment: Hi @Clive the full error is here, https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=PlacesProvider

Comment: That error doesn't relate to the code you've posted. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @DanielBarde, where have you added the square brackets? Clive is referring to this line of code: `angular.module('app.factories', [])`. That should be done before you load the users and places factories.

Comment: Or at least just in Users.js @rvignacio (which is loaded first)

Comment: @Clive i did just that but now i'm getting this error http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/unpr?p0=PlacesProvider

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't attempt to inject the `Places` factory - it's not possible to help you debug code that we can't see

Comment: @Clive I pasted my code above the Places factory i belongs to the app.factory module and is loaded as a dependency in my app.js file in my code above

Comment: @DanielBarde, in the users factory, is this a copy/paste error? `var app = angular.module("app.factories, []");` look at the quotes. Anyways... you should define the app.factories module in a separate file and only load it to add each factory. Look at Mehmet Otkun edited answer, that will work.

Comment: You have module dependencies in your code; no service dependencies. `Places` is a service.

Comment: Whoops! Just emptied my browser cache and reloaded and everything seems to be working well now!

Answer (score 2):

In Users factories

```
 var app = angular.module("app.factories", []);
```

In Places factories

```
var app = angular.module("app.factories")
```

Namely, u should use square brackets when u define the module first time, In second time, you must remove it.

Alternatively

```
  (function(){
    'use strict';
      angular.module('app', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.utils', 'app.configs', 'app.factories', 'app.ctrls']);

   //define your app.factories module here
    angular.module('app.factories', []);
   // define your app.ctrls module for all controls
    angular.module('app.ctrls', []);

   //then you can use them in any where without square brackets
 })();
```

Comment: Maybe it's better if you define the module in a factories.js file. If you add a new factory and place it before the users one the app will stop working.

Comment: What @rvignacio said. Stick it in its own module file so you don't get confused. It also gives you a natural place to add config/run methods if you eventually need them